# Gradle publishing error with android library plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle

I get the following error when trying to publish an android library to a local repository that is defined in init.gradle.

```
> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
```

I have defined my maven repositories in ~/.gradle/init.gradle so that they can be used in all of my projects.

```
allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    repositories.ext.mavenMyRepo = {
        repositories.maven { 
            name "MyRepoSnapshot"
            url "file:/home/me/mvn/snapshot"
        }
        repositories.maven { 
            name "MyRepoRelease"
            url "file:/home/me/mvn/release"
        }
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenMyRepo(MavenPublication) {
                repositories.maven {
                    if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                        url "file:/home/me/mvn/snapshot"
                    } 
                    else {
                        url "file:/home/me/mvn/release"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

In my project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

archivesBaseName = 'my-android-lib'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
}

task jar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'compileReleaseSources') {
    from 'build/intermediates/classes/release'
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Version": version)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "sources"
    from 'src/main/java'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenMyRepo(MavenPublication) {
            pom.withXml {
                asNode().appendNode('description', 'Android Library')
            }
            groupId 'my.group'
            artifactId archivesBaseName
            // from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine when I do this with other 'java' only projects.  I have read other questions that suggest that the issue may be with the order of applying the plugins, but that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know why the android plugin would cause this issue?

P.S.  I am using gradle (v2.6) on the command line, not Android Studio.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32746509/1329791

The error went away, but now project.version is unspecified in the init script so the wrong repository is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working with version 2.1.2 of the android plugin.